# problems with title spacing in a longtable only section

Tags: spacing, longtable, titlesec

Consider the following MWE, where I use the `titlesec` package to add negative spacing before a section heading. (I've exaggerated the negative space for effect). It works as expected in general, except it doesn't work after a section consisting of only a `longtable`. Any advice?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{-24pt}{0pt}  %exaggerated

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\section{Section with text before table}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{longtable}{l|l}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
\end{longtable}

\section{Section with longtable only}

\begin{longtable}{l|l}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
\end{longtable}

\section{Section with text only}

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Good example!

Comment: It has to do with \@afterheading.  Evidently longtable does not "consume" its effects.  \leavevmode will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo! Adding `\leavevmode` immediately after `\section{Section with longtable only}` fixed the problem.